# Reconfiguring RAID 1 Array after Replacing RAID Controller

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge

I just replaced the RAID controller in a PowerEdge 1850 is their a way to recreate the RAID config from the old RAID controller without having to wipe the drives and rebuild the array from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that RAID controller stores the RAID config in a special format on the drives themselves. When the server boots up, so long as it has all of the drives in it, it should be able to read that config and continue on its merry way. You may be prompted during boot about whether or not to accept the config read off of the disks, but the default should be 'yes'.

Comment: IT would appear something like that; apparently I had one hard drive in addition to the RAID controller go bad and the new RAID controller was trying to read the bad hdd instead of the good one.

Comment: Yep, dual failure on RAID setups can be hell, and on top of this, it might require matching firmware on the RAID controller. RAID controller failure should be very rare though. If not, change model/range :-)